# variable in .txt file

Tags: vb.net, notepad

I would like to have my variable in .txt file. I've never done it before (I mean putting variable in .txt file). What should my file consist?
And what should I put into my vb project, when I want to use If function. 
ex. my variable name = dzien
value= 0

```
Private Sub zapisz_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)      Handles zapisz.Click
     Open "C:\Plik.txt" For Append As #1 
If dzien = 0 Then
TextBlock1.txt += "dzien jest 0"
End IF
```

Does this function work if in .txt file there is my variable?

Comment: What do you mean by have a variable in a text file? Text files just contain text.

Comment: he wants to have a config file. So that he doesn't have to start the program with parameters and he doesn't want to have hard coded parameters. Therefore you have to read the file and analyze the string.

Comment: @lorenzalbert - Possibly. I certainly can't read all of that in the question.

Comment: I would like to have data in my .txt file, that will be changing while my application is runs.

Comment: Look into Serialization.

Comment: For what purpose? What is this for?

Comment: Imagine; I want to put kind of "exercising plan" for my app. There will be button "new training" and "continue training" . New training will open new page and change (variable?) from .txt file from 0 to 1. Continue training after each click will increase the variable +1 and save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.  For instance, you could store the value in a text file, a binary file, an XML file, an ini file, or a configuration file.  The simplest option is to use the built-in settings framework.  To do that, go to your project properties and click on the settings tab.  Create a new setting called "DZien" and set the type to an integer.  Then, in code, you can access and set the value in the config file like this:

```
Dim dzein As Integer = My.Settings.Dzien.ToString()  ' Read value from config file
My.Settings.Dzien = 5  ' Write new value to config file
```

Rather, if you want to store a single number in a text file, you could do it like this:

```
Dim dzein As Integer = Integer.Parse(File.ReadAllText("C:\Plik.txt")) '  Read value from text file
File.WriteAllText("C:\Plik.txt", dzein.ToString())
```

In your case, where you are writing a windows phone app, you could do it like this:

```
Partial Public Class_1
    Inherits PhoneApplicationPage
    Private dzien As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            dzien = CInt(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings("dzien"))
        Catch ex As KeyNotFoundException
            dzien = 0
        End Try
        If dzien = 0 Then
            ' ...
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_1_Unloaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Unloaded
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings("dzien") = dzien
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So what should I put into my .txt file?
I get 2 errors (vb.net)
Declaration expected
ReadAllText is not a member of "System.IO.File"

Comment: The text file would need to start by containing a valid integer value, or you could add some exception handling to the code so that it defaults to zero if it fails to read an integer value.  What version of the .NET framework are you working with?  `ReadAllText` was added in version 2.0.  If you can't use that, you'll want to look at `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`.

Comment: I'm using higher version than 2.0. It's 4.xxx. I'm using vb 2010.
I don't know what you mean by "valid integer value". .txt can contain only "0" ? Or I have to type (I really dunno); Dim dzien as Integer, dzien=0

Comment: I was trying to do it with the first way, but I don't have the "settings tab".

Comment: Here's the instructions on how to use the settings screen in VS2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25zf0ze8.aspx

Comment: By a valid integer value, I mean a string which can be parsed into an integer by the `Integer.Parse` method.  For instance, `0` is a valid integer, but `Kevin Bacon` is not.

Comment: I DON'T have settings tab! I only have Application, debug,compile and references, that's why i'm asking ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17777/discussion-between-dawid-lis-and-steven-doggart)